# How can i find The number of repetitions column in other table?

Tags: sql-server

I have two table:
table code:
[image]

table detail:
[image]

i want write query for find number of repetitions of code number into the detail table.i want this output:
[image]

Comment: please include what did you try already. and what research have you done.

Comment: @rahulroy9202 thanks for read my problem,i think my question is very clear,i want read code 1216 from code table and find it how much repeat in table detail and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working. Check link for a working fiddle.

```
SELECT code, COUNT(*) FROM detail GROUP BY code;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ed74/5

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need a simple `group by` query.

```
SELECT C.CODE, COUNT(D.NAME) as REPEAT
FROM CODE C LEFT JOIN DETAIL D ON C.CODE = D.CODE
GROUP BY C.CODE
```

Comment: you will not get the rows that aren't on the detail table